# Using ignoreCase and unequal to a string literal to change code

Tags: java

I need to modify this code so that the app ends with an entry of a "N" or "n".  Right now, it will only end if with an input of anything other than "y". I am to use _____.equalsIgnoreCase() and (!______.equals()) in my answer to manipulate the code.

I am very new to Java, and have been sitting here coming up with nothing.  Any help appreciated!

```
String choice = "y";
        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            // get the invoice subtotal from the user
            System.out.print("Enter subtotal:   ");
            double subtotal = sc.nextDouble();

            // calculate the discount amount and total
            double discountPercent= 0.0;
            if (subtotal >= 200)
                discountPercent = .2;
            else if (subtotal >= 100)
                discountPercent = .1;
            else
                discountPercent = 0.0;

            double discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
            double total = subtotal - discountAmount;

            // display the discount amount and total
            String message = "Discount percent: " + discountPercent + "\n"
                           + "Discount amount:  " + discountAmount + "\n"
                           + "Invoice total:    " + total + "\n";
            System.out.println(message);

            // see if the user wants to continue
            System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.next();
            System.out.println();
```

Comment: Please don't tag [tag:javascript] when you mean [tag:java]. Unless you find hamster sandwiches tasty.

Comment: I clicked whatever 'tag' came up that was suggested, which must of been javascript.  Was in a hurry ...hurry to eat hamster sandwiches...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
boolean success = false;
do {
  choice = sc.next();
  if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    success = true;
  } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
    success = true;
  }
} while (!success);
```

Comment: Nope, when I entered 'y', it completed the program.

Comment: You need to replace the line `choice = sc.next();` with what I wrote, and leave the line `while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))` as it is, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try if (choice.equalsignorecase ("n")) break; after you get the user input at the end.

Comment: Closer! It keeps me in the program if a 'y' is entered, but if I press something like a 0, it still boots me out, and I need it to only end the program if a "N" is entered.